# How do I Set height of a grid inside a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, relativesource

The `DataTemplate` is used in an `ItemsControl` inside a `UserControl`. The UserControl is added multiple times inside a stackpanel. (pfew)

I need to be able to determine how many children the stackpanel has. I assumed this was possible using the `FindAncestor` mode, but I'm afraid I need your help.

Here's the XAML logic:

```
<StackPanel Name="BeforeTournament" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <UserControl ...
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" FontSize="14" />
            <ItemsControl Name="MatchList" ItemsSource="{Binding Matches, Mode=OneWay}" Width="400" Margin="-7,20,0,0"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="MatchTemplate" Width="390"
                          Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}},
                                       Path=(Children.Count * 300}"
                          Margin="0,0,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>

    //Duplicates below, same logic to determine width
    <UserControl></UserControl>
</StackPanel>
```

So I would basically like to know how many UserControls have been added to the stackpanel and be able to use this amound of children to calculate the height of the grid inside the DataTemplate.

The FindAncestor relative source is giving me an error saying that Children is not supported in a relative context.

Comment: I could have misunderstood your question, but can't you just count the number of items in the data bound `Matches` collection?

Comment: i am sure whatever you are trying to do, should not need height adjustments like this, try using better hierarchy of controls to get it working.

Comment: Sheridan, I guess he wants to know rendered size from no. of items in control

Comment: Muds is right, `{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}.Children` is not possible inside a relative source and I can't set the height from code-behind because you can't make changes to controls inside a DataTemplate.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is probarbly better ways, but I think you can use a IValueConverter and pass the stackpanel as a parameter. Then return the number of children multiplied by 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I said in the comment there should be a better way to do this, but I'am pretty sure one way to do this is to use a converter. Pass the stackpanel as parameter and return the number of children multiplied by 300(If that is what you want)

I have tried this code and it works. Just for show i added two usercontrols manually. I have also tried putting the usercontrols in a seperate xaml file.

Main.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StackpanelConverter x:Key="StackpanelConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Name="BeforeTournament" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <UserControl>
        <Grid Height="200" Background="Brown">
            <TextBlock Name="txtTitle" FontSize="14" />
            <ItemsControl Name="MatchList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="10"  Width="400" Margin="-7,20,0,0"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="MatchTemplate" Width="390" Background="Blue"
                   Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Converter={StaticResource StackpanelConverter}}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
    <UserControl>
        <Grid Height="200" Background="Brown">
            <TextBlock  FontSize="14" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="10"  Width="400" Margin="-7,20,0,0"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Name="MatchTemplate" Width="390" Background="Blue"
                   Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Converter={StaticResource StackpanelConverter}}"
                      Margin="0,0,0,50" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Example of converter: (this is written in notepad so there might be errors)

```
 public class StackpanelConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var stackpanel = value as StackPanel;
        var height = stackpanel.Children.Count;
        return height*300;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Tell me if I still don't understand the question :)

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but you're not seeing the problem here.
The grid is positioned inside a DataTemplate. Since this is dynamic, I can't pass any parameter that isn't included inside the binding context. This includes the stackpanel that is a parent of the UserControl. The UserControl isn't even present in the XAML file where the StackPanel is located.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Ill look into it :)